# Configure Client Application Services in code

Tags: c#

How can I configure Client Application Services without an app.config file?

I'm unable to add a membership provider, or set the default provider. Is there a way to programmatically set these or use an embedded resource instead of the app.config file?

Answer (score 0):

Set the provider at runtime:

MembershipProvider userProvider = Membership.Providers[UserProviderName];

Ref: [Changing the membership providers ApplicationName during runtime. How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852635/changing-the-membership-providers-applicationname-during-runtime-how)

Comment: The list of providers in Membership.Providers does not contain the provider I need. I need to add it without an app.config

Comment: Sounds like maybe you are trying to load an assembly without a refernce, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804267/asp-net-application-reference-to-assembly-in-programmatically-loaded-assembly  Then instead of using a factory like Membership.Providers, you'd just call new on the relevant provider.